# Error estimation with matlab

Tags: math, matlab, curve-fitting

I have a data set which I need to fit to two quadratic equation:

```
f1(x) = a*x + b*x^2
f2(x) = b*x^2
```

Is there a way to estimate the error where I take into account both the standard error in the measurement and the error in the curve fittig?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "standard error in the measurement"?

Comment: @JimClay: When ever you measure something, there is a certain error to that measurement. I want to plot my simulations results and there is some deviation between the simulations (which is natural). This deviation is the standard error multiplied by the square of the number of the measurements

Comment: Yes, I know that measurements have errors.  I wanted to know how you knew what the error was (it's a simulation, so you have the "true" numbers), and what you meant by "standard".  I still don't know for sure what you mean by standard, but I assume you mean the standard deviation.  Is that right?

Comment: Are you using a gaussian distribution to model your measurement error?

Comment: You might have better luck with this on http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Yotam - I removed the "standard-error" tag since that really means the standard error terminal on the computer, on this site.

Comment: @JimClay, No. I have several independent simulations running under the same limitations.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean that "error due to measurement" is the distribution of the measured values around the "true" predicted values by some physical law, and "error in curve fitting" is caused by fitting the data to a model that does not fully capture the physical law.

There is no way to know which kind of error you are seeing unless you already know the physical law.  For example:

Suppose you have a perfect amplifier whose transfer function is Vo = Vi^2.  You input a range of voltages Vo and measure the output Vi for each.

If you fit a quadratic to the data, you know that any error is caused by measurement.

If you fit a line to the data, your error is caused by both measurement and your choice of curve fitting.  But you'd have to know that the behavior is actually quadratic in order to measure the error source.  And you'd do it by... fitting a quadratic.

In the real world, nothing ever behaves perfectly, so you're always stuck with your best approximation to the physical reality.

Answer (score 0):

If you have errors in your measurements as well as in your response variable, you might try fitting your models using [Orthogonal Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares). There's a [demo](http://www.mathworks.com/products/statistics/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/stats/orthoregdemo.html) illustrating exactly this process that ships as part MATLAB's Statistics Toolbox.